# I was trying to migrate from struts 2.3 to 2.5. I changed dependencies of struts to 2.5

Tags: java, struts2, dependencies, log4j2, classnotfoundexception

I changed the dependencies of struts to 2.5, and upgraded dependency for log4j2 as I read about migration so made some changes in the struts.xml
Web.xml. Also changed filter dispatcher to org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter in the web.Xml file

It is still giving

```
Logservleterror SRVE0293E java.lang.classnotfound.classnotfoundexception: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
```

Do I need log4j2.xml file also in the resources folder of my project?
What else can be done to resolve this error?
Are there any other changes required to be done after updating the filterdispatcher

Comment: I tried Everything whatever mentioned in the above link. Still getting the same error!

Comment: If you tried everything why is there still an error regarding `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`? That class doesn't exist in 2.5.

Comment: Yess correct, it's no more now... I got something new